# Strings/ features in Turicreate decision tree

Tags: decision-trees

I am trying to create a prediction model by using a decision tree with Turicreate. While my problem does involve numbers, it also involves strings and ultimately I want it to return the string 'true/false'. Are Turicreate decision trees able to process strings as input and output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the package, but [the documentation](https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/userguide/supervised-learning/linear-regression.html) suggests that strings as input will be handled internally by dummy-encoding (with a reference level).  The linked section is for linear regression, but is linked to from the [Advanced Features section](https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/userguide/supervised-learning/decision_tree_classifier.html#advanced-features) of the decision tree page, so I assume that applies.